# Use sqlite3 in vscode for c++（undefined reference to `xxx'）(I have use -lsqlite3)

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I'm going crazy for this problem. I downloaded the source code and pre-compiled files of sqlite3 according to the tutorial, and used vs to compile, got the `sqlite3.lib` and `sqlite3.exp` files, and put it in the `C: \ sql` folder. Then I created the project in vscode, and put `sqlite3.h` in the root directory of the project, and created the following test code.

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#pragma comment(lib, "c:\\sql\\sqlite3.lib")
int main() {
    sqlite3 *db = NULL;

    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open("Student.db", &db);
    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    } else
        printf("open mydata successfully!\n");
    sqlite3_close(db);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My `tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "gdb",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-LC:\\sql",
                // "${fileDirname}\\src\\Account.cpp",
                // "${fileDirname}\\src\\Person.cpp",
                // "${fileDirname}\\src\\Date.cpp",
                // "${fileDirname}\\src\\System.cpp",
                // "${fileDirname}\\src\\Administrator.cpp",
                "-lsqlite3",
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But no matter how I modify the tasks.json file, I still get the following result. I am really too lost. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUXavQh.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUXavQh.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUXavQh.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUXavQh.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "c:\\sql\\sqlite3.lib")` is for the Microsoft compilers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I am still a rookie in programming. But after I tried to delete this sentence, the error remained unchanged. I still don't understand why the link is not on ```sqlite3.lib```

Comment: The way I generate ```sqlite3.lib``` is to use the lib command in the ```vs command prompt.```
```lib /def:sqlite3.def / machine: x64```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally download the sqlite-amalgamation source and compile it as a regular source file. SQLite made it very easy and you should have no problem https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

I don't mess with static/dynamic libs when I don't need to. The problem may occur because of which compiler compiled the library (ie ms compiler, mingw, clang, etc). There's a chance you may be mixing them causing the error. I suspect the precompile one is using ms compiler. From memory clang works with libs compiled with ms compiler (clang depends on it). mingw doesn't depend on it and won't use ms compiled libs

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest that I don't need to compile it into a .lib file because mingw does not depend on it. I should compile the source code of sqlite3 directly.

Comment: Or I should not use mingw?

Comment: It's overkill to use a .lib file (or dll). Yes compile sqlite3 directly. It depends on nothing and will compile on any platform (to my knowledge). It's the easiest piece of software I have ever compiled. I don't write C++ on windows so I can't suggest mingw vs ms vs clang. Use whatever you like. On linux I use vs code with the C++ addon and codelldb (not sure how well it works on windows).

Comment: Thank you! When I used the linux system to compile, it was successful.